# Snapshot of KyotoCabinet database concurrent to writes

Tags: database, multithreading, kyotocabinet

Is it possible in Kyoto Cabinet database to make safely a database snapshot and concurrently write to database in the same time ?

The KyotoCabinet database class kyotocabinet.DB (for JAVA among other languages) 
provides the following methods:

```
 boolean    dump_snapshot(String dest) // Dump records into a snapshot file.
 boolean    copy(String dest) // Create a copy of the database file.
```

Both operations could be quite long. I did not test this methods directly but by using the `kcpolymgr` utility from different process. I found that the operations blocks other writer process-es (`kcpolymgr set`) until the operations finish.

Is the behaviour the same when writes come from other threads in the same process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot or copy of the database **blocks** concurrent database operations from other threads and processes.

To test within the same process I exposed the Kyoto Cabinet methods by JMX and tried to `set` or `get` any value from the database while concurrently a snapshot or a copy were being in progress.

Methods `set` and `get` were waiting for the concurrent snapshot or copy to finish.

---

I found a part of the [documentation](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/spex.html#Pseudo-snapshot) that covers the issue. It mansions the cache hash database but it looks like the other database implementations behaves similarly:

> Chiefly for the cache hash database and the cache tree database, the
>   "pseudo-snapshot" mechanism is provided. The `BasicDB::dump_snapshot'
>   dumps all records into a stream or a file. The`
>   BasicDB::load_snapshot' method loads records from a stream or a file.
>   Although the operations are performed atomically, they don't finish
>   momentarily but take time in proportion of the database size with
>   **blocking the other threads**. Because the format of pseudo-snapshot data
>   is common among the all database classes, it is useful to migrate
>   records for each other.
>
> ```
> db.dump_snapshot("backup.kcss"); 
> db.load_snapshot("backup.kcss");
> ```